# Excel VBA: Copy dynamic range to last row based on offset value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a couple of issues I need help with.

Where a user has selected an active month (row 3) by using a data validation drop down I want to allow the user to press a button which will 
1) Add a formula to the location 2 rows under where "Active Month" was identified
2) Copy this to the last row in the work book
3) Select that row remove formulas and replace with the values only.

The first issue I get is a 1004 message. The code works if I enter a basic formula e.g. =5+10 but not for this one

2nd problem. Where I have Range("Z5:Z" & Lastrow) I don't understand how I can make this select based on the column value of where the user selected the "Active month" it could be AA, AB, AC etc

The code is below where I'm getting the 1004 error.

```
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Cells.Find(What:="Active Month", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

ActiveCell.Offset(2).Select
Range("Z5:Z" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(F5,Dormant!A:A,1,0)),Z4,"")"
```

Comment: regarding the 2nd problem:  my possibly-not-so-simple approach would be to use Cells() references and the # of the column.  you know your range of AA(col 27) through 12 months (col 39), and can use Find() within the fixed range to determine the correct column reference

Comment: **the code is below where I'm getting the 1004 error** .... on what line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Add a formula to the location 2 rows under where "Active Month" was identified
>
> 2) Copy this to the last row in the work book
>
> 3) Select that row remove formulas and replace with the values only.

You are getting `Application Defined Error` becuase you did not pad up the double quotes in your formula. Replace `""` with `""""` in that formula so that it becomes `"=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(F5,Dormant!A:A,1,0)),Z4,"""")"`

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**). I have commented the code. If you still have any doubts then simply ask :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long, StartRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim ColName As String, myformula As String

    '~~> Change formula here
    myformula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(VLOOKUP(F5,Dormant!A:A,1,0)),Z4,"""")"

    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find the "Active Month"
        Set aCell = .Cells.Find(What:="Active Month", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If Found
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Get offset to where it was found
            StartRow = aCell.Row + 2

            '~~> Get the column name where it is found
            ColName = Split(.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1)

            '~~> Find last row in that column
            Lastrow = .Range(ColName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            '~~> Identify the range and insert formula and convert it to values
            With .Range(ColName & StartRow & ":" & ColName & Lastrow)
                .Formula = myformula
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I did try this out but all that happened was the date header column got deleted.  How would this code know where the last row was in my data set? Usually I set the range to a bit of data where there are no blanks, in your example it seems to be looking at range (which is currently blank)

Comment: Deleted? I am not deleting anything? unless the date header is below "Active Month"

Comment: Hi, yeah it looked like it was overriding the contents of the cell. I tried using StartRow = aCell.Row + 3. There was still no view that the formula was entered. I may need to make a change of approach as the formula will change per line to reflect the heading. I think I might need to change the approach by performing a number of else statements.

Comment: `There was still no view that the formula was entered.` that is because of `.Value = .Value`. Comment that line and then check :)

Comment: Great stuff - the formula was entered. It was only going to the first couple of rows then stopped. How would this code know where the last row was in my data set? Usually I set the range to a bit of data where there are no blanks. There is no information in the columns next to the active month

Comment: is there a way to set the last row indicator to column D so the code is able to identify when to stop?

Comment: if you want last row of column "D"  then change `Lastrow = .Range(ColName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to `Lastrow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. Currently the code gets the last row in the column where "Active Month" is found

Comment: Got it - this was outstanding and worked perfectly. Now I need to learn this